# Optimal way of accessing parent view property (Ionic 2, Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm testing Ionic 2 and Angular 2, and I've got a doubt about accessing to parent view's properties.

Per example, I've got a test app in which my view is a list of items, and when I click one item, I enter to their details. Pretty straightforward, huh? Well, that details view has got functions that edit the element, and then apply the changes.

For this, I use three different ways:

- One is to pass the object reference and just edit it, which edits it back in the list (I guess this is pretty optimal)
- Before the typical navCtrl.pop(), pass a parameter via navParam to the function "ionViewDidEnter()", which executes just when you come back to a view, and filter it there, so you can perform the task you desire. Problem: it doesn't work (probably it's a bug).
- Here comes the krakken: when **removing** the element, this won't work, since I have **to remove it from the list**, per example, with the typical list.splice(index, 1);

I found two different methods of performing this: you can either pass the new view a reference of the list, or you can access it from the NavController, just as I do here:

```
  remove(){
    let list = this.navCtrl._views[0].instance.list;

    for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        if(list[i].id === this.contact.id){
            list.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }
```

Here I have another example of this weird technique, reusing the edit view for creating a new element:

```
  editContact(obj){
    if(this.onEdit){
        this.onEdit = false;
        this.editBtnTxt = "Edit contact";
        if(this.onCreate){
            this.navCtrl._views[0].instance.list.push(this.contact);
            this.navCtrl.pop();
        }
    }else{
        this.editBtnTxt = 'Apply changes';
        this.onEdit = true;

    }
  }
```

Although this works pretty nicely and isn't throwing any errors, I guess I'm just being somewhat lucky, because: how do you know the index of the view you want to access, if you're not in a simple test project like this with two views, per example? I guess there can be a lot of errors with this way of doing things.

But as it works, and it seems to be more optimal than passing tons of parameters, or using localStorage as a "global" variable, I'm sticking with this by the moment.

What I would like to know, is... **which way is the most optimal of accessing parent view properties?**

Comment: The optimal way to do this is TO NOT DO THIS. You should instead make a service that shares data between components and pass parameters if need be in a push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to avoid accessing the parent view.

Use `@Output()`s in the child and `(someEvent)` bindings in the parent and notify the parent about the actions it should take on the model.

If they are not direct parent child (like when the child is added by the router) use shared services with observables instead.

Comment: Can you add an example of these things? I haven't heard about the @Output decorator and don't know how shared services are in Ang2.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html covers both topics. They are very basic building blocks of Angular2